# How to share link to Google Drive file via Google+?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-plus, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to share a Google+ post from Android with DeepLinkId attached. This deeplink should lead to Google Drive file.

I've managed to share a file from Google Drive (I've got DriveFile.resourceId) and it's clear to how to share Google+ post with deeplink.

But how to attach Drive file link, which is also should become shared to person who opens deep link?

Comment: Its impossible to automatically share to those opening. Share it as public beforehand.

Comment: Thanks, assigning to file public permission solved the issue